# Edges staying during subdivision

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

[image: Subdivision Surface not affecting one edge]

Total noob here, been messing around with this for a while but it seems like the faces are stuck to this one edge. Everywhere else they have been smoothed nicely, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hi, I think the normals of the faces are not in the right direction. Go to edit mode select the object and press Shift + N to recalculate the normals.

Comment: It could be an extra interior face, as well. Select one of the sharp faces in edit mode and press <kbd>h</kbd> to hide it. Then look inside and see if there is an extra face... When you're done press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to unhide the faces.

Comment: Unsure how to mark it as the answer but Gladys solution worked instantly. I don't understand what you mean by the normals of the faces but Shift + N solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: The problem]
In the example above, the sharpness is an extra interior face.

[image: Select some nearby geometry]
Select one or more of the sharp faces in edit mode and press <kbd>h</kbd> to hide it.

[image: Look, a hidden face!]
Then look inside and see if there is an extra face... When you find it, delete it!

[image: And Bob's your uncle!]
When you're done press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to unhide the faces and head back to object mode.

Answer (score 0):

@goose An helpfull tool to see the orientation of the faces is to click on the the little arrow for the overlays (1) it can be done in object mode and also in edit mode and then check face orientation. It then gives a blue color or red color to the faces. The blue color indicates that the normals are pointed outwards this is the right way and the red color of the faces indicates that the normals are pointing inward. <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> gives you a pop-up menu for the normals.

[image: face orientation]